# What method Apache camel uses to delete the file using delete=true, is it JDK FileUtil.deleteFile(file)

Tags: java, architecture, apache-camel, delete-file

I have been asked to provide details on how Apache Camel delete functionality works behind the scene, the method used and if the deleted file can be recovered as we are deleting PCI file. Based on my understanding, the files once deleted cant be recovered but is their a documentation that proves the same from Apache Camel.

Comment: There's something better than documentation. There is the source code.

Comment: i did try looking at the source code, but its confusing like how it relates to delete=true , There is public static boolean deleteFile(File file) {
 method in Org.apache.camel.file class which further calls file.delete(); looks like part of rt.jar method from JDK8.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the answer:- the files are deleted using java.io.File#delete() method, where calling File.delete() permanently removes the file, without going into the recycling bin or anything similar.